# Importing code from one script into another script

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so I searched for beginner projects in order to practice my skills. I came across a project on Edureka where you have to program a simple word game called Hangman (https://www.edureka.co/blog/python-projects/#hangman). The whole code consists of different scripts, and a part of one script is then improted into another, like in this case (Words.py)

```
import random

WORDLIST = 'wordlist.txt'

def get_random_word(min_word_length):
    ...
```

and then (Hangman.py)

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from words import get_random_word
```

So they first created a function in a script Words.py and then imported it in another script Hangman.py. My question is: why is a code sometimes separated into several scripts and then parts of one imported into other? Can't one script just contain eveyrthing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basic organisation. Imagine a library would glue every new book to a stack of the old ones. Lord of the Rings would turn from a door stopper to a door. After defeating Sauron, the reader would smoothly transition to The Little Mermaid, before plunging into 50 Shades of Grey.

Small files are easier to stomach. If every file serves only one topic, you know quickly where to look. You also immediately know what does not belong to the topic, without having to read through commentary.

Multiple files allow for non-linear organisation. The building blocks of a program rarely follow a single, linear chain of interactions. Loosely coupled components are easily represented by individual files, and folders allow to add external structure.

Distinct files are easier to reorganise. As complexity grows, components move to sub packages, and sometimes you just need to clean up. A file can simply be moved as a whole. Copy/Pasting to migrate code is more work, especially if you have tacked on all the structuring manually.

Basically, a single file is easy to write. Multiple files are much easy to read, maintain and manage. For software development, the later is much more important. Even if you are working alone, future-you does not know everything that past-you has done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple files to create sub-modules helps keep the code organised and makes reusing code between projects/functions much easier.

Functions and variables defined within a module importable into other modules and allows you to scope your function and variable names without worrying about conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer